# Sub string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to sub string "send "

```
 send = name +"  "+telNo1 +"  " +address+"  " +telNo2+"  " +telNo3+"  "
        + email+"  " +bday+" " +address+"   " +occupation;
```

I pass send to another method and i need to sub-string send  and get values to separate string variables.

Comment: Are you saying you have a string, and you want to divvy up the string into the respective variables? That sounds like a regex job.

Comment: Can you please add your desired output to your question, otherwise everyone has to guess what you want

Comment: give the sample o/p format.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ... packing values into a string, passing the string to a method, and unpacking the string into its components is the wrong way to solve whatever real problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you means `split` ?

```
string[] splitted_word = send.Split(' ');
foreach (string x in splitted_word)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```